# c sharp webservice access microsoft database (mdb)?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

How to access the mdb data via asmx web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference from where you access your database. Generally `OledbConnection` ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) is your friend for connecting to a Access database.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the database in a web service is the same as you are coding in a class in the data access, nothing will be changed.